# Create multiple logins with the same permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a server instance with 100 databases in it.

I need to create 20 new logins with access to 65 of the 100 databases. They all need to have the exact same permissions. The 20 logins should not even see the other 35 databases in the Object Explorer.

What is the best and most efficient way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: How does this question differ from [the other you recently asked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260389/2-logins-with-the-same-permissions), other than the number of logins and databases? The answer is the same.

Comment: For hiding databases, deny `VIEW ANY DATABASE ` to the login.

Comment: I feel like this one is clearer. The number of logins is very important, because my question is about an efficient way to have 20 logins with the same permissions. I don't want to have to create 20 logins + 1300 users manually. Isn't there a way to setup a role that contains these permissions for the 65 databases and then simply assign the role to each of the 20 logins?

Comment: The most efficient way depends on what scripting languages you know.  Do you know enough PowerShell to automate this?  If you don't know any scripting languages well enough to do this, then you'll just have to do a lot of copying/pasting and finding/replacing to generate the scripts. Create a role in each database and assign permissions to it.  Then create the logins, and add them to the database roles.  For any given action, click the Script button at the top of the SSMS dialog and that will give you a script that performs the action.  You could do this in an hour with no automation.